# Sending mails with no data on Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel

I got this:

```
Mail::send('emails.orders.attach', null, function($message) use($mail, $subject) {
        $message->from(Config::get('mail.from["address"]'), Config::get('mail.from["name"]'))
            ->to($mail, 'Sender name here')
            ->subject($subject);
    });
```

And laravel is telling me:

```
 Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, null given
```

I don't need send data, my email template is not sending data except an attached which has all data for the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an empty array

```
Mail::send('emails.orders.attach', [], function($message) use($mail, $subject) {
    $message->from(Config::get('mail.from["address"]'), Config::get('mail.from["name"]'))
        ->to($mail, 'Sender name here')
        ->subject($subject);
});
```

You'll notice the `[]` instead of `null` as the second parameter in the example above.

On a side note, `'mail.from["address"]'` probably won't function as you expect. That'll look for a key called `from["address"]` including the double quotes inside the mail.php config file.